# How to get the TextPrompt to display when using a custom stylebook

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I'm trying to setup a stylebook for my Delphi XE5 mobile firemonkey app and according to the DocWiki I'm selecting one of the supplied stylebooks and customizing that.

The problem is each one of the supplied stylebooks that I've tried causes the TextPrompt (a property of TEdit) in my tEdit to disappear.

It doesn't seem to be a matter of it having the same color as the background.  I've tried different color backgrounds.

So why is it doing this? What do I need to do to have the textprompt display when using a custom stylebook? do I need to create a custom tEdit in order to have a TextPrompt?

Gary

Comment: What do you mean by 'custom stylebook'? Are you creating your own style, modifying a built in one or loading one of the other pre-supplied ones? If so it will need to be a mobile specific one to have all the needed features.

Answer (score 0):

only put **TLabel** into style and set

```
StyleName="prompt"
```